# How to store and retrieve list[String] List[(String,Int)] into mapr/hbase table using put and get

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, mapr

**Business case :**

I need to persist array/list of objects for particular row-key.
For exampel for row-kwy r1, have column c1 with schema as `List<Struct<String,Int>>` and value as (("first",1),("second",2)) and another column c2 with schema `Array<String>` and value ("a","b","c")

Now I need to persist this information onto HBase/MapR binary table.
I used Put as

```
Put put = new Put("r1".getBytes)
```

I have list a 'list1' of type of `array<struct<String,Int>>`

```
byte[] colValue1 =list1.toString.getBytes

put.addColumn("columnFamily".getBytes, "c1".getBytes, colValue1);
```

Another `List<String>` say `list2=("a","b","c")`

```
byte[] colValue2 = list2.toString().getBytes
put.addColumn("columnFamily".getBytes, "c1".getBytes, colValue1);
```

using hTable.batch api we are persisting data into hbase/mapr.

As in MapR, every attribute stored in binary and don't have any information of it's schema though I have schema as well and try to read with schema but still I am unable to get list/collection data from MapR i.e. `List<Struct<String,int>>` or simple `List<String>`, finally it is coming as String and need to do play with

With scan or get it is returning everything in string format and we are not getting element value with schema.

can someone help me in resolving it.

Comment: Are you using java? Won't `list.toString` just return the name of the class?

Comment: Actually I am using scala but it is straight forward have some collection of object and need to store and retrieve from MapR DB. As per your suggestion if I don't use toString then how can I convert collection of object into byte[], I know we can do with ObjectOutputStream but can you provide some example or sample code as not sure if this is also work or not .